# Mysql database server keeps going off

Tags: mysql, vps, virtualmin

My Mysql database server keeps going off. I have to login to virtualmin/webmin to start it again. My server is a VPS 1 gig ram with Ubuntu installed. I have not installed any new software apart from the ones that came with virtualmin. How do i keep my sql server on. I am hosting a wordpress and a forum site on it. I have an average of roughly 55 runninh processes

Comment: You haven't said what Ubuntu release (assuming you're talking server, if other you should also specify that too) you are using, and `virtualmin` is not a Ubuntu package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=virtualmin) so details of non-Ubuntu packages installed may also be useful.

Comment: Did you have a look at the log files (`/var/log/mysql/`)?